# Why is my slot not being found in qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've been stuck for a while trying to connect this pushButton to a function that plays the media already coded in. It gives the same error. Yes I included Q_Object in the classes. What's going on

In my main window.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mediafile = new Player;
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(pressed()),mediafile,SLOT(playFile(mediafile)));
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I have q_object in my classes but I get an error saying

```
QObject::connect: No such slot Player::playFile(mediafile) in     ../musicplayer/mainwindow.cpp:12
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'pushButton')
```

I don't understand why I get this I have a function called playFile in the Player namespace class

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QDebug>

class Player : public QMediaPlayer
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Player();
    ~Player();


public slots:
    void playFile(Player *);

private:
    //Player file;

};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

Here is the implementation.

```
#include "player.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
Player::Player() {
}
Player::~Player(){
    //delete file;
}
void Player::playFile(Player* file){
    file->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("Average White Band - Overture.mp3"));
    file->setVolume(50);
    file->play();
}
```

Here is the main window header file. Is there something I'm missing maybe even the basics about qt

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <player.h>
namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:

    Player *mediafile;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Lastly guys if you have an easier way I want to hear it.
But just tell me what I did wrong here so Ill know for later..

Comment: what is `file`?

Comment: its the name of the parameter that I used for that function specifically

Comment: When you use a parameter in a slot is to receive data from the signal, if you realize that parameter is inappropriate.

Comment: oh I didn't know that it worked so close together like that. So how should I do this? Because I tried taking the parameter out and doing function with another variable inside the class. But then the program just crashed.

Comment: Check and test my solution.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you stop using the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros if you are using Qt 5.x and instead use the new compile-time-checked `connect` syntax. That way you'll get a compile time error when signals and slots don't match up, instead of things just not working at runtime. Start reading here: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters that are used in the slots are to receive parameters from the signals, and in your case it is not necessary.

Also another problem is that in the class inheriting from QMediaPlayer you have not called the parent constructor, so it works you must modify your code to the following:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "player.h"

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Player *mediafile;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mediafile = new Player;
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(pressed()), mediafile, SLOT(playFile()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**player.h**

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <QMediaPlayer>

class Player : public QMediaPlayer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Player(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR, Flags flags = Flags());
    ~Player();
public slots:
    void playFile();
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

**player.cpp**

```
#include "player.h"

Player::Player(QObject *parent, Flags flags):QMediaPlayer(parent, flags)
{

}

Player::~Player()
{

}

void Player::playFile()
{
    setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/eyllanesc/Music/Coldplay/A Rush of Blood to the Head/Track 8.mp3"));
    setVolume(50);
    play();
}
```

Comment: It works! Honestly man I really have to thank you a whole bunch really appreciate it. Was stuck on this for a good 2 days lol. I have one question though was it because I had the unnecessary pointer to the functions inside playFile also